# Rendering individual FieldCollectionItemEntity fields

Tags: php, drupal-7

I need to render individual fields from a field collection to allow me to tweak the field order, field contents, remove wrapping DOM nodes, etc depending on certain criteria.

I've been reading through [this thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/1155752) as it seems to be the best resource on the matter but I cannot figure out why this field collection renderer is not behaving.

It simply outputs nothing.

`node--component-icon-promo.tpl.php`

```
<? if (!empty($content['field_icon_promo_items'])) : ?>

  <div id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

    <?php foreach ($content['field_icon_promo_items']['#items'] as $entity_uri): ?>
      <?php 
        $item = entity_load('field_collection_item', $entity_uri); 
      ?>

      <?php foreach ($item as $item_object ): ?>

        <?php print render($item_object->field_cta); ?>

      <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

  </div>

<? endif; ?>
```

Adding a `dpm($item_object);` right before the `print render` outputs this.

[image: Field output]

And changing the `<?php print render($item_object->field_cta); ?>` to `<?php print render($item_object); ?>` just results in errors.

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class FieldCollectionItemEntity
>   could not be converted to string in include() (line 99 of
>   /var/www/html/sites/all/themes/xerox/templates/node--component-icon-promo.tpl.php).

I know that's because the $item_object is just that, an object which [render doesn't like](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/render/7.x). The field collection bit of the API just seems like a total mess.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would suggest to use it like this way, using entity_metadata_wrapper:

```
<? if (!empty($content['field_icon_promo_items'])) : ?>

  <div id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

    <?php foreach ($content['field_icon_promo_items']['#items'] as $entity_uri): ?>
      <?php 
        $item = entity_load('field_collection_item', $entity_uri);
      ?>

      <?php foreach ($item as $item_object ): ?>

        <?php 
            $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $item_object);
            $field_cta = $wrapper->field_cta->value(); 
            //render your values with your own html or using theme_link function
        ?>

      <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

  </div>

<? endif; ?>
```

For more help on meta data wrapper visit [this link](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers)

Comment: This code didn't work quite like I needed it to but the metadata wrapper pushed me in the right direction!